# .htaccess question: http://www.example.com/contact should show http://www.example.com/contact.php (without redirecting)

Tags: .htaccess

As said in the Title,I want that http://www.example.com/contact should show http://www.example.com/contact.php. And important: without redirecting.

Unfortunately my .htaccess Code does not work:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php [L]
```

What could be the reason for this? Please help me out how to fix it :(!

**EDIT: SOLVED. Google helped me out.
Adding Options -Multiviews was the Solution. Thanks everyone!**

Comment: Do you want force all extensions as `.php`?

Comment: No! Only for this specific page.

Comment: (and after that 1-5 more, but that is it).

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you have to put the `/` at the beginning of `contact` because it's part of the path.

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/contact$ contact.php [L]
```

Comment: No, does still not work. The rule is not even recognised (I put http://www.google.com instead of contact.php there).

Comment: That's odd. Both of these methods work fine on my server. Are you sure you have mod_rewrite enabled?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make the URL at the top show .php when going to the URL without PHP would be to redirect the browser to it. The easiest way to do that in most apache instances would be:

```
Redirect permanent /contact http://example.com/contact.php
```